Slanted stripes on a page
I would like some full sized slanted stripes on the page; that's all.
This is what I did so far:


html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.flag-strip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 15px;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
    z-index: 1;
}

.flag-strip.red {
    background-color: #D90012;
    top: 9%;
}

.flag-strip.blue {
    background-color: #0033A0;
    top: 10.5%;
}

.flag-strip.orange {
    background-color: #F2A800;
    top: 12%;
}

@media (max-width: 878px) {
    .flag-strip.red {
        top: 11%;
    }

    .flag-strip.blue {
        top: 12.5%;
    }

    .flag-strip.orange {
        top: 14%;
    }
}
<div class="flag-strip red"></div>
<div class="flag-strip blue"></div>
<div class="flag-strip orange"></div>



But the user shouldn't have a horizontal scroll bar, and the stripes should be really full sized -- there shouldn't be any endings visible on the page.
How can I make it work like that?

I’d scrap your current approach and just use an SVG background image instead.

Is this purely for visual effect ie do you need the stripes to be elements in the DOM for some other reason? If not maybe consider a background-image perhaps as linear-gradients.

What is @media (max-width: 878px) for? Do you actually want non equal stripes on smaller screens?

You can do this entirely in CSS with linear-gradient as the background.


html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
.flag-bg {
    height: 100%;
    
    --flag-a: 10deg;
    --flag-h: 30px;
    --flag-pos: 20%;
    --flag-color1: #D90012;
    --flag-color2: #0033A0;
    --flag-color3: #F2A800;
    --flag-antialias: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(calc(180deg - var(--flag-a)),
      transparent        calc(var(--flag-pos) - var(--flag-antialias)),
      var(--flag-color1) calc(var(--flag-pos)),
      var(--flag-color1) calc(var(--flag-pos) + var(--flag-h) / 3 - var(--flag-antialias)),
      var(--flag-color2) calc(var(--flag-pos) + var(--flag-h) / 3),
      var(--flag-color2) calc(var(--flag-pos) + 2 * var(--flag-h) / 3 - var(--flag-antialias)),
      var(--flag-color3) calc(var(--flag-pos) + 2 * var(--flag-h) / 3),
      var(--flag-color3) calc(var(--flag-pos) + var(--flag-h) - var(--flag-antialias)),
      transparent        calc(var(--flag-pos) + var(--flag-h))
    );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
<div class="flag-bg"></div>




A good start, but it doesn't give the same result as the original (the stripes are all the same height in this answer whereas they shrink in the original with viewport) and it isn't 'entirely CSS' as it also added an element in the DOM.

@AHaworth If you show their snippet in full screen, the strips are equal. I expect OP actually wants that. And this can be applied to body instead of .flag-bg.

Yes, I suspect you are right but perhaps OP needs to confirm.

For the visible endings at either side, you could make the .flag-strip extra-wide (like 120vw) and instead of starting at left:0 you could start it 20px off the view (i.e. -20px) - see below:
.flag-strip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120vw;
    height: 15px;
    left: -20px;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
    z-index: 1;
}

if you do not want any scrollbars, you can also make the .body hide the overflow in both directions (not just X)
 body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

See runnable demo:


html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flag-strip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120vw;
  height: 15px;
  left: -20px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.flag-strip.red {
  background-color: #D90012;
  top: 9%;
}

.flag-strip.blue {
  background-color: #0033A0;
  top: 10.5%;
}

.flag-strip.orange {
  background-color: #F2A800;
  top: 12%;
}

@media (max-width: 878px) {
  .flag-strip.red {
    top: 11%;
  }

  .flag-strip.blue {
    top: 12.5%;
  }

  .flag-strip.orange {
    top: 14%;
  }
}
<div class="flag-strip red"></div>
<div class="flag-strip blue"></div>
<div class="flag-strip orange"></div>



